# Which project is throwing "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

I have read through lots of SO answers about this problem, but I'm still not sure what's at the root of the issue.  When I try to run nopCommerce 4.0 on my localhost, I get the error "Unable to load one or more of the requested types."  When I look in LoaderExceptions, I see 12 instances of "Could not not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc...'" and 2 of "Inheritance security rules violated by type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacWebTypesModule'".  Unfortunately, there are many projects in this solution and, as far as I can tell, System.Web.Mvc is in all of them.  Is there a way to determine exactly which project or projects are having trouble finding this file?

[image]

Comment: That seems like part of an exception. Doesn't the stack trace tell you from where the exception originates?

Comment: It didn't.  All I could see was that the System.Web.Mvc wasn't found.  I did, however, fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was able to solve this on my own.  It turns out that there was a plugin I had added that was causing the issue.  I'm not sure yet what's wrong with the plugin, but I was able to avoid the error by removing the plugin and clean/rebuilding Nop.Web.Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you were able to find a workaround. My best guess is that the plugin you imported depends on a different version of System.Web.Mvc than your project. From the error message it appears that the framework requires v5.1 which is a version released in 2014.